# Можно ли переопределить compareTo для разных полей

Tags: java, сортировка

Допустим есть класс `Account` с полями `first` типа `int` и `second` типа `String`:

```
class Account {
    int first;
    String second;
}
```

Чтобы можно было выполнить сортировку в классе `Account`, нужно:

1) реализовать интерфейс `Comparable`;

2) а после, переопределить метод `compareTo()`

Ок, делаем:

```
class Account implements Comparable<Account> {
    int first;
    String second;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Account compare){
        int value = ((Account) compare).first;
        return this.first - value;
    }
}
```

Но метод `compareTo()` переопределяется для `определенного типа` значений. В нашем случае выше - для типа `int`.

Чтобы выполнить сортировку в порядке возрастания мы делаем следующее:

```
Account a = new Account();
Collections.sort(a);
```

Логика: метод `sort()` интерфейса `Collections` вызывает наш переопределенный метод `compareTo()`.

А если мне нужно теперь выполнить сортировку по полю `second` типа `String`, как быть тогда?

Comment: Второй параметр...

Comment: Вы имеете виду в методе `compareTo()` создать второй параметр? Насколько я понимаю, нельзя создать - ведь в базовом `compareTo` только один параметр.

Comment: Нет конечно. `Collections.sort`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понимаю вас до конца, что вы имеете виду.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `Collections.sort(a, Collections.sort());` - начало такое?

Comment: Интересно мне как это `Collections.sort(a,....` нынче стало обрабатывать не списки? Бред. Работать не будет.

Comment: Для  первого поля `Collections.sort(l, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.first));`.
Для второго поля `Collections.sort(l, Comparator.comparing(a -> a.second));`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @And, ну он создание списка пропустил и вместо него скопипастил создание объёкта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно выкрутиться примерно так:

```
class Account implements Comparable<Account> {
    int first;
    String second;

    public static boolean sortByFirst=true;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Account account){
        if(sortByFirst)
            return this.first - account.first;
        else 
            return this.second.compareTo(account.second);
    }
}


List<Account> listOfAccount;
//blah-blah
Account.sortByFirst=true;
Collections.sort(listOfAccount);  //сортировка по полю first
Account.sortByFirst=false;
Collections.sort(listOfAccount);  //сортировка по полю second
```

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать ещё варианты.